# Not able to create a shortcut on the desktop for URL from Chrome

Tags: .desktop

I have tried creating a desktop entry. I can see it but when I click on it, it opens up in text editor. The content of desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to Ask Ubuntu[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to Ask Ubuntu
Type=Link
URL=http://www.askubuntu.com/
Icon=text-html
Type=Link
URL=http://www.askubuntu.com/
Icon=text-html
```

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Have you made Desktop entry executable? What is the output of `ls -l filename`? Have you tried open with other application?

Comment: Click on the notification icon and then this comment in the list to come here.  Your second question "disappeared" when it got moved to meta.askubuntu.com, since it was really about using this site, not about Ubuntu.  You seem to have created an "edge case", where technically correct actions don't help the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the line :

```
Exec=/usr/bin/x-www-browser file:///<PATH TO FILE>/file.html
```